# Rename columns based on Pattern PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| item_name | price_for_2k  |  qty_1  |  price_for_5k |  qty_2 | price_for_10k | qty_3 |     url     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Samsung Z |   10000       |    5    |    9000       |    10  |  7000         |   20  | amazon.com  |
| Moto G4   |   12000       |    10   |    10000      |    20  |  6000         |   50  | ebay.com    |
| Mi 4i     |   15000       |    8    |    12000      |    20  |  10000        |   25  | deals.com   |
| Moto G3   |   20000       |    5    |    18000      |    12  |  15000        |   30  | ebay.com    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to apply regex pattern like this `"(price_per_[0-9]+)k"` and replace `k` in column name with `000`.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| item_name | price_for_2000  |  qty_1  |  price_for_5000 |  qty_2 | price_for_10000 | qty_3 |     url     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Samsung Z |   10000         |    5    |    9000         |    10  |  7000           |   20  | amazon.com  |
| Moto G4   |   12000         |    10   |    10000        |    20  |  6000           |   50  | ebay.com    |
| Mi 4i     |   15000         |    8    |    12000        |    20  |  10000          |   25  | deals.com   |
| Moto G3   |   20000         |    5    |    18000        |    12  |  15000          |   30  | ebay.com    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the column whith the new name when condition is verified:

```
for column in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(column, column.replace("k", "000") if column.startswith("price_for_") else column)
```